# check same names in two array of objects in javascript /typescript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two array of objects

```
array1=[{name:'apple',deleted:false},
       {name:'road',deleted:false},
       {name:'tree',deleted:false}]
```

and

```
array2=[{name:'apple'},
       {name:'tree'}]
```

what I want is : **if array1 object has same names in array2, I want to change value of "deleted" in array1 to true .** eg : `{name:'apple',deleted:true}`

expecting resulting array1:

```
array1=[{name:'apple',deleted:true},
           {name:'road',deleted:false},
           {name:'tree',deleted:true}]
```

here you can see , only `apple, tree` has `deleted=true`, because `array2` has only 2 names : `apple` and `tree`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `forEach()` to loop array1 and use `include()` to set value of deleted

```js
const array1=[{name:'apple',deleted:false},
       {name:'road',deleted:false},
       {name:'tree',deleted:false}]
       
const array2=[{name:'apple'},
       {name:'tree'}]
       
array1.forEach(el=> el.deleted = array2.map(foo => foo.name).includes(el.name))
console.log(array1)
```

Answer (score 3):

you can :

- loop on array1 with forEach for sample
- use some function to set deleted boolean

  ```
  deleted = array2.some(elem2 => elem2.name === elem.name)
  ```

```js
const array1 = [{
    name: 'apple',
    deleted: false
  },
  {
    name: 'road',
    deleted: false
  },
  {
    name: 'tree',
    deleted: false
  }
]

const array2 = [{
    name: 'apple'
  },
  {
    name: 'tree'
  }
];

array1.forEach(elem => elem.deleted = array2.some(elem2 => elem2.name === elem.name));

console.log(array1);
```

Comment: thank you man, this does works perfectly on console, but I am getting array1 as undefined for some strange reason, when used in my code. I guess it is because I am using typescript or because I am altering array1 ( the answer from @VMT ,just below one ;does work perfect )

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of `deletedItems`.
2. [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the items and update the `deleted` property using the `Set`.

```js
const 
  items = [{ name: "apple", deleted: false }, { name: "road", deleted: false }, { name: "tree", deleted: false }],
  deletedItems = [{ name: "apple" }, { name: "tree" }],
  deletedSet = new Set(deletedItems.map((d) => d.name)),
  updatedItems = items.map((i) => (deletedSet.has(i.name) ? { ...i, deleted: true } : i));

console.log(updatedItems);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.map` and `Array.find`:

```js
let array1=[
  {name:'apple',deleted:false},
  {name:'road',deleted:false},
  {name:'tree',deleted:false}
];

let array2=[
  {name:'apple'},
  {name:'tree'}
];

array1 = array1.map(item1 => array2.find(item2 => item1.name == item2.name) ? {...item1, deleted:true} : item1);

console.log(array1)
```